# How to parse unknown args with sub parsers

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to catch all unspecified args to my program. Typically I would do this using `parser.parse_known_args()`. However, this does not seem to work with subparsers.

Minimal example:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description='Command to create and manage your characters.',
)

parser.add_argument(
    "--debug", action="store_true"
)

#sub_parsers = parser.add_subparsers(
#)

#sub_parsers.add_parser(
#    'list', help='List characters.', #TODO: Fill this in
#)

args = parser.parse_known_args()
print(args)
```

Uncommenting the above subparser lines and running the command `python test_arg_parse.py test` causes the following error:

```
usage: test_arg_parse.py [-h] [--debug] {list} ...
test_arg_parse.py: error: invalid choice: 'test' (choose from 'list')
```

I would expect in this minimal example for the namespace to be printed and a list of the unexpected args, in this case `["test"]`.

Comment: It's complaining that 'test' is not a valid subparser name.  `subparsers` is a kind of positional argument.

Comment: `positional` arguments are assigned first, and then tested for type and choice.  So with your setup, any non-flag string will be assumed to a subparser name.